# Recommended twitter gem for ruby-on-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-gem

I've found a couple of different twitter gem (for ruby-on-rails) out there:

http://twitter4r.rubyforge.org/

http://twitter.rubyforge.org/

But I'm wondering if someone can rate them and provide a recommendation of either one or a new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've used both twitter4r and twitter (outside of Rails though) and over time seem to have stuck with the latter since I find it easy to use and well documented.

Answer (score 30):

Use [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter). It's actively maintained.

Answer (score 3):

Grackle http://github.com/hayesdavis/grackle is pretty good. It's very clean, actively developed and well documented. It supports both Basic and OAuth authentication.